# jq arithmetic operation in object constructors on Windows

Tags: cmd, jq

Assuming there's a `sample.json` file with contents like this:

```
[
 {
  "a": 1, 
  "b": 2
 }
]
```

if I run a `jq` command as follows (Windows 10 command line):

```
> type sample.json| jq ".[] | .a - .b"
-1
```

but if I try to build an object with a key, whose value would be the result of subtraction operator, I can't:

```
> type sample.json| jq ".[] | {c: .a - .b}"
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '}' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:                                                                                                                                                                        .[] | {c: .a - .b}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        jq: 1 compile error
```

what kind of a "quoting issue" might this be, and how to "fix" it? thanks!

EDIT: forgot to mention, it's the same with `+` operator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the expression in parentheses:

```sh
jq ".[] | {c: (.a - .b)}" sample.json
```

```json
{
  "c": -1
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1Ghfd8fFbN)

---

```sh
jq ".[] | {c: (.a + .b)}" sample.json
```

```json
{
  "c": 3
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/youRCg-WMe)

Comment: jq has such weird precedence.